# Creating setup wizard on Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my application I need to ask the user some information in the beginning. Like Google asks users when they first launch the phone.

Using Java and Android, how do I make the same kind of setup wizard for my application? I could create multiple activities and when moving to the next page in the wizard I'd launch that. That doesn't seem a good way to do it.

I'd like to use Eclipse's GUI builder to design it.

Like This [Image](http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Android-5.0-Lollipop-Setup-app-1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one activity for the setup wizard, and you change the content with fragments, or you open the setup wizard activity again with intent (close the existing one) and you pass some parameters, based on those parameters you show different content or you could use this https://github.com/romannurik/android-wizardpager

Comment: Thank you =D You save me